# Scala, how do I replace static members?

Tags: scala, oop, static

I wan't to build a class Animal which I can find the number of animals were created. In Scala there is no option to static variable, so how can I implement such functionality in Scala (I am looking for non-specific solution)?

Thanks!

For example in Java:

```
public class Amimal {
    static int number_of_aminals = 0;  
    public Animal() {
        number_of_animals++;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be:

```
import Animal

class Animal {
  Animal.increment()
}

object Animal {
  private[this] var _count = 0

  def increment(): Unit = { _count += 1 }
  def count: Int = _count
}
```

Though you might want to use AtomicInt.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a companion object for your case class which acts as a singleton:

```
case class Animal(name:String) {
  Animal.incrementAnimal
}

object Animal {
  def incrementAnimal = ...
}
```

However, be advised that following the approach above will require you to use mutable variables (variables defined by `var` instead of `val`) which is discouraged in Scala.  So you may want to revisit your design to use immutable values.

Comment: It seem less nicer then Java. Thanks you too!